# Wordpress 6.x / PHP 8.x deprecated warnings in development environment

Tags: theme-development, errors, debug, wp-debug

The problem:

I want to run Wordpress 6.x with PHP 8.x in development mode - meaning `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` but Wordpress 6.x [partial support for PHP 8.x](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/references/php-compatibility-and-wordpress-versions/) throws a lot of deprecated warnings which do a lot of mess on the screen and also mess with cookies and REST API.

Setting `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);` in `php.ini` or `wp-config.php` does not solve the problem because Wordpress overwrites this setting when you set `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` which you want normally have for the  development.

The solution is no straight forward and I couldn't find fast, either on Stack or anywhere else so below I will answer my own question and solve the problem for others.

Comment: error logging should be done to a file rather than printing to the screen, but keep in mind that support for 8.0 is incomplete, I'd advise avoiding 8.0 for now if these are a concern, especially when using plugins and purchased themes

Comment: For development personally I like to see errors on the screen. Regarding the 8.0 readiness - yeah that is my concern - normally I use only narrow set of plugins (which are frequently updated) so at the moment I'll try and see what happens. The thing is that PHP is recently really quick with deprecating it's PHP versions 7.4 is supported only till the end of 2022 so there's really not much time and given the lifetime of an average template I thing one should really try the 8.x as soon as possible.

Answer (score 8):

change the line that sets error_reporting in wp-includes/load.php, probably around line 450:

```
if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
    error_reporting( E_ALL);
```

just add the  `& ~E_DEPRECATED` bit so it becomes:

```
if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
    error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED );
```

[wordpress rant] - why would they not put something like this in the config file? In my (painful) experience of writing plugins & child themes for wordpress it's impossible to use debug mode not because of problems in my code but deprecated code in literally dozens of files throughout the codebase, ALWAYS. This renders WP_DEBUG useless. And don't get me started about how simple it would be to implement by default the multi-environment support I always have to hack into the wp-config.php file (I assume everyone else probably does this too) :-( [rant over(!!)]

Comment: This rocks. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this. It's unbelievably stupid that WP doesn't respect the settings set in the php config file, that it overwrites the error reporting settings with its own idea of what error reporting should be, that this isn't configurable, and finally, that it requires editing the core files to fix.

Answer (score 7):

The key to the solution is `enable_wp_debug_mode_checks` filter but to use it you have to do something special.

As the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/enable_wp_debug_mode_checks/) says:

> This filter runs before it can be used by plugins. It is designed for
> non-web runtimes. Returning false causes the WP_DEBUG and related
> constants to not be checked and the default PHP values for errors will
> be used unless you take care to update them yourself.
>
> To use this filter you must define a $wp_filter global before
> WordPress loads, usually in wp-config.php.

Then when you disable this default error reporting overwrite - you can set your own.
So the final solution looks like this:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

if (WP_DEBUG) {
  define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
  define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);

  // disable friendly non informative error messages
  define('WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER', true);

  $GLOBALS['wp_filter'] = [
    'enable_wp_debug_mode_checks' => [
      10 => [[
        'accepted_args' => 0,
        'function'      => function() { return false; },
      ]],
    ],
  ];
}

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
```

Unfortunately it turns off automatically also deprecated messages from your own code, but what can you do until Wordpress solves its deprecated code fragments.

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you. So stupid that WP doesn't give us an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

I went through all the proposed answer on the different topics about Wordpress 6.x and PHP 8.x.

After trying everything, even the mu-plugin not working, I could fix it by setting the `error_reporting()` at the end of the `wp-config.php` file because for some reason, after `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` was not enough.

Here is what I added but anything would work:
`error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);`

Comment: Glad you solved it, but you shouldn't still be getting deprecated warnings nowadays though.

Comment: Indeed, I reported it to the plugin author (buddypress)